# Use an NSString to programatically access or create a method in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, methods

I am trying to use an array of strings dynamically access methods at runtime within my class. For now the methods are already there, eventually I want to create them.
Is this possible?

For example:

```
bool nextLevel=NO;
for(NSString * match in gameLevels)
{

    if([match isEqualToString:self.level])
    {
        nextLevel=YES;
    }
    else if(nextLevel==YES)
    {
        self.level=match;
        nextLevel=NO;
    }
}
//access method named self.level
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your question is not clear, please elaborate more

Comment: @KhawarAli I think he wants to have it so he can do `[self @"methodThatDoesSomething"]` where the string comes from possible functuon names in an array

Comment: Are you saying the NSString contains the names of methods to call? Yes that's possible. Look at NSSelectorFromString

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. Martin has it exactly.

Comment: There are several ways to call a method by name.  See, eg, the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-TPXREF105).  Creating a method is a bit (actually, a whole lot) more difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the link Hot Licks, I've found the method to dynamically create : objc_allocateClassPair - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use:

```
NSSelectorFromString(selectorString)
```

In your case, the `selectorString` would be:

```
NSString * selectorString = @"setLevel:";
```

This is 'setLevel' instead of 'level' because the Objective-C runtime will automatically expand dot properties to these selector names when assignment occurs.

Comment: you mean `setLevel:`?

Comment: Why yes I do. Good catch.   The colon is necessary because we are passing a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To access a method based on a string, check the other answer.

To add a method in the runtime you need to create a IMP function or block.

If using a function, could be something like:

```
void myMethodIMP(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    // implementation ....
}
```

You could also use a block like this:

```
IMP blockImplementation=imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id _self, ...){
    //Your Code here
}
```

Then you need to add the method, like this:

```
class_addMethod(yourClass, @selector(selectorName), (IMP) blockImplementation, encoding);
```

The encoding part is a special runtime encoding to describe the type of parameters your method receives. You can find that on the Objective-C runtime reference.

If you receive dynamic arguments on your generated methods, you need to use the va_list to read the values.